# Even after permissions are updated, I still get the error permission denied for relation users

Tags: postgresql, permissions, php

I'm getting the error `ERROR: permission denied for relation users` and have tried to update privileges using both

`grant all privileges on all tables in schema ops to my_user`
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE the_table TO my_user`

In the Grants tab of DBVisualizer I can see that the my_user user has the privileges `DELETE`, `INSERT`, `SELECT`, `TRUNCATE`, and `UPDATE`.  `IS_GRANTABLE` is set to NO for all of these. Yet I still get this error. What is there left to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497352/error-permission-denied-for-relation-tablename-on-postgres-while-trying-a-selec

Comment: @Mihai That would just grant read only privileges, yes? Doesn't my `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` include that?

Comment: What's the statement that produces this _permission denied_ error?

Comment: @DanielVérité `INSERT INTO my_schema.users (      user_id,
        username,
        email,
        role,
        fullname) VALUES (1,
        'the_user',
        'email@email.com',
        NULL,
        'userfirst1 userlast1'), (2,
        'the_use2r',
        'email1@email.com',
        NULL,
        'userfirst2 userlast2')`

Comment: OK. Now why do the GRANTs of the question target a different table (than `users`) and a different schema (than `my_schema`)?

Comment: Please don't copy your questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892175/even-after-permissions-are-updated-i-still-get-the-error-permission-denied-for). Instead, use the "flag" link to ask a moderator to move them to a different site.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to privileges on the `TABLE`, a role needs privileges for the `SCHEMA` and the `DATABASE`. The most likely candidate is the schema. If so, this additional [`GRANT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-grant.html) would be the fix:

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA my_schema TO my_user;
```

Or at least:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA my_schema TO my_user;
```

Comment: Also try reconnecting after the privileges are given

Comment: OMG THANK YOU - `GRANT USAGE...` was what I was missing!